# Is there a modulo function with offset in Python?

Tags: python, modular-arithmetic

Is there a function that computes modulo but with offset like in second output?

Something like `mod(23,13,-6)==-3` where `-6` is offset. It is equivalent to `(23+6)%13-6==-3`.

I know that I can define my own function but I am not sure it would be as fast as built-in function.

```
d=13
off=int((d-1)/2)
print([x%d for x in range(d)])
print([(x+off)%d-off for x in range(d)])
```

---

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1]
```

**Update:**

The variant with offset equal `(d-1)/2` can be defined also this way (see Wikipedia link in my comment below):

```
d=13
print([x-d*round(x/d) for x in range(d)])
```

---

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1]
```

Comment: I've never heard of a built-in function like this in any language.

Comment: It is standard in Mathematica. And see also definition by rounded division of modulo in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo.

Comment: Same here. I would create it yourself.

Comment: But since it needs besides `%` also `+` and `-` operations in one definition and `round` and `-` and `/` in second definitions it would be slower than ordinary `%`. But I need the same speed as with ordinary `%` so I would need to adapt the original algorithm for `%` instead of defining my new in terms of ordinary `%`.

Comment: Unless you’re working with huge integers (where `%` will dominate the runtime anyway!), I feel like worrying about optimizing out two additions while using Python is… odd.

Comment: Numbers are not that big but huge is the number of them. I need to do about `10^9` maybe more modulo operations with numbers under `10^6`.

Comment: Are you using numpy?

Comment: If you need to operate on billions of numbers, using NumPy will get you far more speedup than anything you're trying here.

Comment: Another vote for numpy, it's almost certainly the right tool to be using here.  You could also check out numba and maybe cython for ways of speeding up these sorts of things, but first on the list should be numpy.

Answer (score 0):

I just found this (going to check whether I again any speed improvements over the definitions in OP or not):

Also the down side is that `math.remainder(x,d)` needs additional `int` to convert to integers.

```
import math
d=13
print([int(math.remainder(x,d)) for x in range(d)])
```

---

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1]
```

Comment: Compared to the approach in the question, this trades two additions for two `LOAD_GLOBAL` hashtable lookups, an attribute lookup, and two Python function calls. That's definitely going to be slower :). Back-of-the-napkin benchmarking with IPython's `%timeit` indicates that this is about 33% slower.